# How this simple code is working in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have made simple program which will calulate the sum of first n numbers(stored in varibale c1) and printf them on to the console.

When I run it ,works fine and give me the desired result.For example if I enter 4 from keyborad,it gives me 10 .

But now when I go through it manually ,find it should give a value 9 when I provide input as 4.

Is it code written fine?

```
section .bss
c1 db
section .data
x db "%d"
section .text
global main
extern printf
extern scanf
main:
mov ebx,1
mov eax,0
lea ecx,[c1]
push ecx
push x
call scanf
add esp,8
well_done:

inc ebx
add eax,ebx

cmp ebx,[c1]

jnz well_done
push eax
push message
call printf
add esp,8
ret
message:
db "sum is =%d",10,0
```

Edit:

```
section .text
global main
extern printf
main:
mov ebx,0
mov eax,0
well_done:

inc ebx
add eax,ebx
cmp ebx,4

jnz well_done
push eax
push message
call printf
add esp,8
ret
message:
db "sum is =%d",10,0
```

This above code gives the expected result for sum of first 4 numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by _"it should give a value 9"_? Shouldn't it give the correct result (which is 10)? Or do you mean that is **is** giving you the incorrect result of 9?

Comment: @Micheal it would be confusing but It gives me correct value of 10 when I run it but If you go through this code manually shouldn't  it give 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `scanf` returns the number of items processed in `eax`, thereby overwriting the `0` you have put in there previously. Since you read 1 item, `eax` will be `1` and that explains why you get 10 when you run the code. You should move the `mov eax, 0` down to after the `scanf` and start `ebx` from `0` too.

Other issues: you should use `dd` for your `c1` because an integer is 4 bytes, not 1. You should also zero terminate your format string and put the `message` into the `.data` section as well.

Comment: Thanks Jester,I got your point and probem indeed was what you mentioned.